# Files removal from linux terminal

Tags: linux

```bash
du -sk * -h | grep M
```

The above command will list all the files which have a size of MB. My job here is to remove only these files, any suggestions [image: remove only the displayed files].

```bash
du -sk * -h | grep M | rm -rf *
```

I am unsure on using the above command.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please take the [tour] and read [ask].  You should put everything for the question in text mode, not images.  Your question mentions removing files, but `du -sk` will print the total sum size of directories as well.  Is that what you want?  The command you listed is very dangerous, as `rm -rf *` will remove **everything** !  Clarify your requirement (remove files larger than 1MB or remove directories or both).

Comment: If there are files with greater size, like 1GB+ or with a lower size 1023KB-, they should **not** be deleted? Could you complete the selection criteria for the files to remove?

Comment: The ```rm``` command does remove the files provided on the command line. The ```|``` will not be used, in the command you provided.

Comment: Jay thank you for helping out, only criteria here is to delete the files which gets displayed after executing the above command. (as simple as delete the displaying files)

Comment: may be can we use this - du -sk * -h | grep M > /dev/null as all the displaying files will disappear

Comment: You really want to delete files with an `M` in their name?

Comment: `find` would be a much better tool for this.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @Armali, du -sk * -h | grep M - this command helps to list all the files (files size that are  MB in size) , my job here is to delete only those listed items.

Comment: You seem to be still unaware of the fact that _this command_ also lists files with a name containing `M`.

Answer (score 0):

`find` can be used to select the files and execute the `rm` command.

hummmm, better to test the command line before really deleting files.

Give a try to this:

```
find . -type f -size +1048575c -size -1073741824c -exec rm -v '{}' +
```